# NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error in twitter login using opencart

Tags: php, twitter-oauth, opencart2.x

I uses twitter login in my website. It works on local server. but, in live server shows following error. When, I click on twitter login button using OpenCart.

> NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

I have included twitter library files in library as below

My **login.php** code(controller file)

```
public function twtLoginRedirect() {

    $this->load->library('EpiTwitter');
    $this->load->library('EpiCurl');
    $this->load->library('EpiOAuth');
    /*include(DIR_SYSTEM . "library/EpiTwitter.php");
    include(DIR_SYSTEM . "library/EpiCurl.php");
    include(DIR_SYSTEM . "library/EpiOAuth.php");*/
    $consumer_key = '*******';
    $consumer_secret = '********';


    $this->load->model('account/activity');
    $this->load->model('account/customer');

    $twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    $authenticateUrl = $twitterObj->getAuthenticateUrl();
    if(isset($authenticateUrl) && $authenticateUrl != '') {
        $json['authenticateUrl'] = $authenticateUrl;
        $json['result'] = 'success';
        echo json_encode($json);
        exit;
    } else {
        echo $json['result'] = 'error'; 
        echo json_encode($json);
        exit;
    }

}
```

My **Login.tpl** file (tpl file)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="twtloginredirect();" class="login_twt"> Log In With <span class="login_icon"></span> </a>
```

My Script for redirect to twitter website for login

```
<script>
 function twtloginredirect() {

 $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=account/login/twtLoginRedirect',
            dataType:'json',
            type:'post',
            success: function(res){

                if(res['result'] && res['result'] == 'success') {
                 window.location= res['authenticateUrl'];   
                } else {
                    alert('something is wrong');
                }        
            }
 });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: What does the internal server error log say the error is?

Comment: please check & read. maybe help for you. http://www.opencartnews.com/tutorials/common-opencart-errors-and-how-to-solve-them/

Comment: it wotks HarnishDesign. It shows error in console  **Fatal error: Class 'EpiOAuth' not found in system/library/EpiTwitter
.php on line 13**. if it not found than how it works on local server?

Comment: Have you checked for missing files?

Comment: Yes, I have checked missing files. All Twitter library files have been uploaded.